# How can you delete a Discord channel a bit after creation if there's no activity?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Here's my code:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!create")) {
        var collection = message.mentions.users;
        console.log(collection.array());
        let createdChannel = message.guild.channels.create(`${message.member.displayName}'s Room`, {
            type: 'voice',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                ...collection.map(user => {
                    return {
                        id: user.id,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    }
                }),
            ],
        })
        let timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(createdChannel);
            createdChannel.VoiceState.delete();
        }, 12000);
        client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
            clearInterval(timeout);
        })
    }
});
```

I've been told that I need to resolve the promise, but I just can't figure out why. I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `GuildChannelManager#create()` method returns a promise. Therefore, you should await the method before defining its outcome, as seen below.

In addition, `VoiceChannel` does not have a `VoiceState` property. See the code below.

Also also, `timeout` is a Timeout function. Not an interval. Hence why there's no reason in using `clearInterval()` in this case, but rather `clearTimeout()`.

#### Final Code

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!create")) {
        var collection = message.mentions.users;
        console.log(collection.array());
        let createdChannel = await message.guild.channels.create(`${message.member.displayName}'s Room`, {
            type: 'voice',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                ...collection.map(user => {
                    return {
                        id: user.id,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    }
                }),
            ],
        })
        let timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(createdChannel);
            createdChannel.delete();
        }, 12000);
        client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh my gosh it works!! You're the best, thanks so much

Comment: @BanatatoMelonwi no problem! Would you mind marking my answer as the correct one so other people could see it as well?

Comment: Yeah! Sorry, forgot to cause there was a countdown.